# How do I make a text file from Excel that simply outputs data from Columns A and B?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to simply output Excel data that contains text in Column A and B up to row 10. The format I want the text file to display is:

Column A1,ColumnB1;

Column A2,ColumnB2;

without any quotations on them.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Yes it is possible, writing a vba function to do that :-)

Comment: Do you know of a guide I can use to do this? I tried searching for sample codes, but I'm not familiar with vba functions, so I couldnt get it right

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim myext As String

 For i = 1 To 10
 mytext = mytext & Cells(i, 1) & vbTab & Cells(i, 2) & vbCrLf
 Next i

 WriteToTextFile (mytext)
 End Sub


 Private Sub WriteToTextFile(ByVal StringToWrite As String)

 Dim fso As Object
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Dim oFile As Object
 Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("write here the path and file name to create")
 oFile.WriteLine StringToWrite
 oFile.Close
 Set fso = Nothing
 Set oFile = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sadly with your code, they are separated by a space. I wanted them to be separated by a comma (no space) and the line to end with a "';" This was what was troubling me as when I tried to format layout, I kept getting syntax errors.

Comment: How about the desired commas in each record??

Comment: i see you allready got an answer for that..@hideyuki pls mark it as answer if it suits you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Johnathan's code above and substitute it with this line instead

```
mytext = mytext & Cells(i, 1) & "," & Cells(i, 2) & ";" & vbCrLf
```

Answer (score 0):

Or...

```
Sub MM()

Open Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\desktop\example.txt" For Output As #1

For i = 1 To 10
    Print #1, Cells(i, 1).Value & "," & Cells(i, 2).Value & ";"
Next

Close #1

End Sub
```